# Scene not showing up in render

Tags: rendering

I just created a VFX video, all is fine except that the object I added do not show up in the render, I only get the original video without all the added object... In layout mode and camera view, all good but in render, only the original video show... I did check if they were set to visible for rendering and they all are... Could someone help? It is getting annoying all those little error in each step because the documentation is kinda poor

Comment: Are the render layers set up correctly? Could you show some images of your problem?

Comment: I don't think it's the documentation. It's just too easy making any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was a video strip in the Video Sequencer. This clip was there when I initially edited the video before Montion tracking. So only the frame from that video was always rendered. As another post [suggests](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275216/57735), you can disable Video Sequencer in Output properties -> Post Processing -> untick Sequencer